# How to prevent user from downloading my Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-sharing

I have made a few useful spreadsheets for my company.

I want to put them on Google Sheets, so my colleagues can use it online to make inputs and get results.  But I do not want them to know the formula (some of them are quite complex and took me a long time to compile).

However, Google allows a user to download the spreadsheet once it is shared.  And once they have downloaded the file as an Excel file, they can pretty much undo all the protection features I have set up in Google.

So is there a way to allow a user to edit a Google Sheet, but not allow them to download it?

Comment: Why don't you want your colleague to know these formulas?

Comment: Related: [Make formulas impossible to find / read](http://superuser.com/q/815272/354511).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to block the download option of a shared Google spreadsheet for editors, it's only possible to block viewers and commenters from doing this.

Also there is no way to block the access to the formulas.

Instead save it as another file format or create a Web App.

Another alternative is to create an add-on to replace the job done by the formulas for scripts.

**References**

- [Prevent viewers from downloading a file - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6115096?hl=en)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview